# Angular component does not update after deleting image

Tags: angular

I've been trying to figure out a way to update my component after I have deleted an image. If I refresh the page it works and is not visible anymore, but I want it to update instantly. I have been trying different methods such as using ChangeDetectorRef etc, but without luck. Any guidance is much appreciated.

My service looks something like this:

```
removeImage(id) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true }); // Create a request option
    const url = this._config.apiEndpoint + 'images/' + id + '/preview';

    return this.http
    .delete(url, options)
    .map(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.ok;
        } else if (response.status === 400) {
            return response.text;
        }
    })
    .catch(this.exceptionService.catchBadResponse)
    .finally(() => { });
}
```

and my component looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['card.component.less']
})

export class CardComponent {
    @Input() card;

removeImage(id) {
        this.cardService.removeImage(id)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
            return res; // returns true
        });
}
```

html looks like this:

```
<div uk-dropdown="pos: top-right; delay-hide: 0; mode: click">
   <ul class="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav">
      <li><a class="uk-dropdown-close textred" (click)="removeImage(card.Id)">Remove image</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have a directive that fetches the images, like so:

```
   @Directive({
   selector: '[card-image]',
   host: {
    '[src]': 'imageData'
  }
 })
 export class ImageSrcDirective implements OnInit {


@Input('card-image') id: number;
configUrl = CONFIG.appConfig.apiEndpoint + 'images/';
defaultImage = CONFIG.images.card;
url: string;
imageData: any = '';
options: RequestOptions;

constructor(private http: Http, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { 
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
}

ngOnInit() {
    if(this.id){
        this.url = this.configUrl + this.id + "/preview";
        this.http.get(this.url, this.options)
            .map(image => image.json())
            .subscribe((data) => {
                const imageurl = data.ImageData.length > 0 ? data.ImageData : this.defaultImage;
                this.setImage(imageurl);
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("err fetching image: ", err);
                console.log("dta: ");
            });

    }else{
        this.setImage(this.defaultImage);
    }
}

setImage(imageurl){
    this.imageData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageurl);
}
```

}

and this directive is used here in the same component html:

```
 <div *ngIf="card.IsMine" class="">
  <a [routerLink]="['', space.Id]" routerLinkActive="active">
    <div *ngIf="!space.IsUploadingImage" class="uk-card-media-top uk-overflow-hidden">
        <img [space-image]="space.Id" class="uk-animation-kenburns" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>

 <div class="uk-card-body">
    <div class="boundary-align">
        <span class="more-btn" uk-icon="icon: more-vertical"></span>
        <div uk-dropdown="pos: top-right; delay-hide: 0; mode: click">
            <ul class="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav">
                <li><a class="uk-dropdown-close textred" (click)="removePreviewImage(space.Id)">Remove preview image</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is there a chance to show us how you use the image component (html and component)?

Comment: Is the removed image inside your component template (I mean before you delete it) or not ? If yes, I don't get why you go through a service for that.

Comment: need code for how you are displaying the images ie whether the images are retrieved from the server or is it static .?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your comments, updated code. Let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya yes, it's retrieved from the server :)

Comment: can you update the code for that ?Both service and component code..

Comment: Now you are confusing me .did you rename removePreviewImage from removeImage or is it different?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. Should be removeImage(spaceid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the issue (not best practice), by fetching the whole object on click instead of the id where the response gives me a boolean that I set to true and when the service is called I set it to false in my component, like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['card.component.less']
})

export class CardComponent {
    @Input() card;
      removeImage(imageObj) {
        imageObj.hasImage = true;
        this.cardService.removeImage(card.Id)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
            imageObj.hasImage = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!